# Eigenvalues of the product of a subblock of a matrix and a subblock of the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, block-matrices

I have a block matrix (which is overall symmetric)

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} 
    A & B \\ 
    B^T & C \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and it's inverse

$$
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \tilde{A} & \tilde{B} \\ 
    \tilde{B}^T & \tilde{C} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that while $A$ and $C$ (along with their tilde counterparts) are both square, they are not, in general, the same size.

I'd like to find the eigenvalues of the product of the subblocks: $A\tilde{A}$.

However, I also have easy access to the diagonalization of $M = U D U^T$, which brings me to the actual question:

Can I make use of the diagonalization of $M$ to compute the eigenvalues of $A\tilde{A}$ (or at least speed up the computation somehow)? All of the matrices are real, if that helps at all.